# Python: Automatically choose parameters for ARMA model

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to fit an ARMA model to time series data. I haven't find any functions that can automatically choose the parameter. Below are the code I wrote however as I am a beginner to Python hence I believe this code can be optimised.

Can someone give me some ideas on how to:

1. do the Vectorization on the double loop
2. quicker way to do the parameter choosing

Much appreciate.

```
    parameter_bound = 3

    # Creating a 2-D array, storing the residuals of two different parameters of ARMA model
    residuals = [[0 for x in range(parameter_bound)] for x in range(parameter_bound)]

    model = [[0 for x in range(parameter_bound)] for x in range(parameter_bound)]

    # Calculate residuals for each parameter combinations
    for i in range(parameter_bound):

        for j in range(parameter_bound):

            model[i][j] = sm.tsa.ARMA(input_data, (i,j)).fit()

            residuals[i][j] = sum(abs(model[i][j].resid))

    # Find the parameters with lowest residuals
    parameters = np.argmin(residuals)

    parameter1 = parameters/parameter_bound

    parameter2 = parameters - parameters/parameter_bound*parameter_bound

    # Use the model with lowest residuals to get prediction data
    prediction = model[parameter1][parameter2].resid + input_data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting, but you could replace your lists with numpy arrays (I don't think it'll improve your specific code):

```
import numpy as np
residuals = np.zeros((parameter_bound, parameter_bound))
model = np.zeros((parameter_bound, parameter_bound), np.object)
```

Also, be aware that np.argmin with axis=None returns an index for a flattened array, if you want to return the model parameters of the model with the lowest residuals you might try:

```
prediction = model.ravel()[np.argmin(residuals)].resid + input_data
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! They are quite helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ljung-Box test:

```
__, pvalue  = sm.diagnostic.acorr_ljungbox(model[i][j].resid)
# if p-value higher than confidence interval 0.95, reject H
if pvalue > 0.05:
    use_parameters = ...
```